# unhighlighting dropdown menu after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownmenu

```
<select id='getbusornew'>
    <option value='News'>BBC News</option>
    <option value='Business'>Business News</option>
</select>
```

Which has css attached to it :

```
.NBSCustomDropDownParent select {
    text-indent: 1px;
    width: 244px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    margin-bottom : 5px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent url("/Style%20Library/NBSImages/NBSCustomDropDownArrow.png") no-repeat 205px center;
    font-family: NBS;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    color: rgb(0, 41, 121);
}

.NBSCustomDropDownParent select option {
    color: rgb(0, 41, 121);
    font-family: NBS;
    font-size: 2.3em;
}
```

However I have one problem, once I have selected an option from the dropdown and the dropdown goes away only showing the option I have selected, It stays highlighted until I click away. Is there anyway to change it being highlighted automatically

Comment: try to set focus on other element, using `$("element").focus();`

Comment: add a onchange event listener to the select where you call $(element).blur();

Comment: Jenson could you add this as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is through a little JavaScript

```
$('#getbusornew').on('change', function () {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

This removes the focus off the element whenever you select an option.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5jbebLgt/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one line JQuery to apply to all `DropDowns`:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {$(this).blur();});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejer910b/)**